# JSF Map showed URL from localhost/testproject/testfolder/all/profile.xhtml to localhost/testproject/profile.xhtml

Tags: jsf, url, web.xml, jsf-2.2

How can i map the URL `localhost/testproject/testfolder/all/profile.xhtml` to `localhost/testproject/profile.xhtml`? I dont want to display the whole structure of the folders behind. I it with URL-Pattern but that doesnt work. Can anyone give me a hint, how this could work in JSF 2.2?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" 
xmlns:web="http://java.sun.xom/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" 
xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" 
id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0">
  <description>Testprojekt</description>
  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.xhtml</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
  <context-param>
    <param-name>javax.faces.DATETIMECONVERTER_DEFAULT_TIMEZONE_IS_SYSTEM_TIMEZONE</param-name>
    <param-value>true</param-value>
  </context-param>
  <context-param>
    <param-name>javax.faces.PROJECT_STAGE</param-name>
    <param-value>Development</param-value>
  </context-param>
  <context-param>
    <param-name>javax.faces.INTERPRET_EMPTY_STRING_SUBMITTED_VALUES_AS_NULL</param-name>
    <param-value>true</param-value>
  </context-param>
  <listener>
    <listener-class>com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener</listener-class>
  </listener>
  <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>faces/users/welcome.xhtml</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>
</web-app>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use a Filter (URL Rewriting) to do it for you.

there are a lot of URL Rewrite Libraries online or you implement your own Filter

some thing like

```
public void doFilter(final ServletRequest request, final ServletResponse response, final FilterChain filerChain) throws IOException, ServletException { 
        HttpServletRequest httrequest = (HttpServletRequest) request;
        String url = httrequest.getRequestURI().trim();
        HttpSession session = httrequest.getSession(true);
        //be aware of infinite loops. in case your url is only profile.xhtml and the redirect contains this file too, so i added the pattern faces before it
        if (url.contains("faces/profile.xhtml")) { // this what pub User see in the url
            StringBuilder forward = new StringBuilder();                       
            forward.append("/testfolder/all/profile.xhtml?");
            forward.append(httrequest.getQueryString());
            request.getRequestDispatcher(forward.toString()).forward(request, response);


        }

                if(!response.isCommitted()){
            try{
                filerChain.doFilter(request, response);
            }catch(Exception ex){
                ...
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You need URL rewriting, I'm using prettyfaces as my URL Rewriting Library.
You can have even friendly URLs

[prettyfaces](http://ocpsoft.org/prettyfaces/)

You just need to add it to your `pom.xml`

```
<!-- for JSF 2.x -->
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.ocpsoft.rewrite</groupId>
  <artifactId>rewrite-servlet</artifactId>
  <version>2.0.8.Final</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.ocpsoft.rewrite</groupId>
  <artifactId>rewrite-config-prettyfaces</artifactId>
  <version>2.0.8.Final</version>
</dependency>
```

Then create `pretty-config.xml` inside your `/WEB-INF/` Folder

in your case, here's an example file of `pretty-config.xml`

```
<pretty-config xmlns="http://ocpsoft.org/schema/rewrite-config-prettyfaces" 
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
   xsi:schemaLocation="http://ocpsoft.org/schema/rewrite-config-prettyfaces
                  http://ocpsoft.org/xml/ns/prettyfaces/rewrite-config-prettyfaces.xsd">

   <url-mapping id="profile">
       <pattern value="/profile" />
       <view-id value="/testfolder/all/profile.xhtml" />
   </url-mapping>

</pretty-config>
```